# Cannot access values from a class attribute ArrayList from a method inside the same class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a Java project for university and I have no prior knowledge of Java. I've simplified the code to try and show the problem.

I have fetched an ArrayList containing one User from the database. This user is proven to be stored inside *users*.

Now, the contents of this ArrayList is never printed when calling *printArray(users)* and *No users found* is printed to the console showing that the array is empty, even though before it was proven to be containing 1 User.

Please see comments inside the *try* section

```
public class UserInterface extends Application {

UserRepo userRepo = new UserRepo();
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
UserController userController = new UserController();
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/gymManager";
    String userName = "root";
    String userPassword= "root";

    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName, userPassword);

        if(conn != null){

            //userRepo.read(conn) takes a Connection and returns an ArrayList<User>
            //users contains 1 user as proven by the next line
            users = userRepo.read(conn);

            //this outputs proves 1 user has been loaded from the database
            System.out.println("How many users loaded: " + users.size()); 


            //takes ArrayList to printArray
            printArray(users);

            //printArray says "No users found indicating the users.isEmpty()"

        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Exception:" + ex.toString()); 
    }
}

public void printArray(ArrayList users){
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No users found.");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
        User currentUser = (User) users.get(i);
        System.out.println("First name = " + currentUser.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

}

```
public class UserRepo implements Repo {
private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public ArrayList read(Connection conn) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Reading users from the database...");
    try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
            String emailAddress = rs.getString("emailAddress");
            String password = rs.getString("password");

            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password);
            list.add(user);
        }           
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + ex.toString()); 
    }
    users = list;
    return users;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show us the method `read` of your `UserRepo` class? You don't have to cast a `User` to `User` if it comes from an `ArrayList<User>` as you do in the `for` loop in `printArray(ArrayList users)` if you make it `printArray(ArrayList<User> users)`.

Comment: I've updated the question to include UserRepo and thanks for the tip :)

Comment: You should consider using local variables instead of fields.

Comment: Could something be calling your `start()` method again in the middle of your test run?  Because of the fact that you're assigning the list to the `users` variable in your repo, a second call has the potential to wipe out the contents of the list.  If that is the problem you can solve it by just doing a `return list;` at the end if your repo method, and getting rid of `users` in your repo completely.

Comment: Can you quickly try to debug by copying the ArrayList? Something like changing `printArray(users);` to `printArray(new ArrayList<User>(users));`?

Comment: Do you really need the `users` in your `UserRepo`? I think you don't and you can just `return list;`. You can as well just write `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);`, after `String query = "SELECT * FROM Users";`, of course...

Comment: Have you tried to make `printArray` a method without a parameter? You are printing `users` (the class attribute) and adding `User` objects to it anyway, so you obviously don't need a parameter.

Comment: Show your actual minimal code that fails. Is ArrayList really `java.util.ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown seems not evidently wrong. However there are dangerous points there.
I think the list `users` should live in a more local scope, as I think it is modified elsewhere.

First a bit of clean-up. To make `list` as pure local result/variable prevents changing it from somewhere else in not shown code. `UserRepo.users` might have been reset, for instance by a new call.

```
@Override
public List<User> read(Connection conn) {
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Reading users from the database...");
    try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
            String emailAddress = rs.getString("emailAddress");
            String password = rs.getString("password");

            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password);
            list.add(user);
        }           
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + ex.toString()); 
    }
    return list;
}
```

You took care to close Statement and ResultSet, the same could be needed for the connection, a second query call with a problem there, could fail.

```
try{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName, userPassword);

    if (conn != null){
        List<User> users = userRepo.read(conn);

        System.out.println("How many users loaded: " + users.size()); 
        printArray(users);
        conn.close();
    }
```

And printArray:

```
public void printArray(List<User> users){
    if (users.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No users found.");
    }
    for (User currentUser : users) {
        System.out.println("First name = " + currentUser.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say what fails without knowing what is inside userRepo.read() method.
Generally speaking to get any data from a database you need to create correct query statement specific to (in your case) DerbyDB.

I never used Derby but to get data from table SELECT statement is usually required, so something like `SELECT * from users`
should return all data from `users` table.

in Java data from SELECT can be stored in [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) so in code it would probably look like this:

```
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS");
```

Next step would be calling ResultSet's `next()` and maybe `getString()` methods but we can't know for sure before we see your UserRepo class contents.

Comment: `UserRepo` is available in the question now. How does your answer address the issue of `users.size()` being 1 while `users.isEmpty()` is evaluating to `true`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I'm able to get data from the database no problem. I've printed it out so I know for sure that it is there.

System.out.println("How many users loaded: " + users.size()); 

Outputs: How many users loaded: 1

And I can even print out name/email for this user